# New Activity from SherlockFragment

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to set a programmatically created button to open a new activity when clicked and use putExtra but the Activity won't even stay on after opening, it stays for 1 seconds and then crashes.

The button code:

```
blogs[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.e("button", "blog clicked");
                    Intent i = new Intent(getSherlockActivity(), Soundcloud.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
```

The new class:

```
public class Soundcloud extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    Log.e("activity", "in activity");
    setContentView(R.layout.soundcloud);

}
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

The manifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.********"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.*****.***.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.*****.***.Soundcloud"
        android:label="Blog" >
    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Logcat:

```
07-24 22:27:22.310: E/pass 2.2(24015): blogs - connection success 
07-24 22:27:23.990: E/button(24015): blog clicked
07-24 22:27:24.280: E/activity(24015): in activity
07-24 22:27:25.080: W/dalvikvm(24015): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f21438)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get it done

```
 blogs[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.e("button", "blog clicked");
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Soundcloud.class);
                    getActivity().startActivity(i);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks but still crashing.

Comment: can you post the stack trace?

Comment: I don't know where the error is. It could be the new class or the fragment. Btw is the logcat not the stacktrace? I showed the logcat in my original post.